# How to create a table in another class with the help of a button from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi in one of my application I have one requirement. Requirement is actually I have one button in one class and if i click on that one table and one label have to add in another class view. Actually I am using splitViewcontroller. Here issue what I am facing is if i click on the button which is available in one class.The table and label are not adding in another class actually I am creating those components programatically.Please let me know how to handle this type of situation.

for your reference:

**Class1 :**

```
-(void)pressAddButton
{

 Class2*classObject=[[Class2 alloc]init];

   [customObject addComponents];

}
```

**In Class2 :**

```
-(void)addComponents
{

        Label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(630, 460, 300, 25)];
        [Label1 setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
        [Label1 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
        [Label1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [Label1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [Label1 setText:@"+ Add-Ons For Consideration"];
        [self.view addSubview:Label1];


        Table = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(620, 530, 500, 90)style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        Table.delegate=self;
        Table.dataSource=self;
        [Table setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:Table];

        Label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(635, 660, 60, 25)];
        [Label2 setText:@"Total"];
        [Label2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        Label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22];
        [Label2 setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22]];
        [Label2 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.view addSubview:Label2];


}
```

Comment: pls add some code or demo class.....

Comment: Hi Spynet please check my question now.

Comment: button in present in view1 after hitting the button it will load the label and table in view2. is that your requirement ?

Comment: Yes correct. View1 related to Class1 and view2 is related to Class2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39468/discussion-between-spynet-and-naresh)

Answer (score 0):

Is this your exact code for creating the label and table view? if so check your origin value(frame value) bcz you set frame value for x axis and y axis out of view so it is not in visible state

```
Label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(630, 460, 300, 25)];
```

this lines making label's frame out of view. You set frame size for all component like this only so check it.

if this is not causing the problem brief your problem little better

How you creating it? do you want to press button in view 1 and it should create dynamic label and table view in view 2 am.

Comment: Hi yohan thanks for your reply. Actually I changes those coordinates and tried but no use. Yes my requirement is press button in view 1 and View1 related to Class1 and view2 is related to Class2.

Comment: Actually I am using splitview controller so I have add button in viewcontroller related to right portion of the screen. And the label and table have to create on view available in left part of the screen.